# How to Save a number from Access database using Parameter?

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, parameters, sql-update

I want to update the number of goals that a player scored so if he scored a goal I want to do an update for his number of goals. I need for it to get the number of goals that the player has from the database and then sum it with the new number that is selected from the website. Can anyone help me, please?

```
protected void SoccerTable_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    using (OleDbConnection sqlCon = new OleDbConnection(connectionStr))
    {
        sqlCon.Open();
        string query2 = "SELECT Achievement FROM SoccerAchievements WHERE PlayerCode = @id";
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query2, sqlCon);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", Convert.ToInt32(SoccerTable.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString()));
        var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        reader.Read();
        string SavedAchievementFromDB = reader["Achievement"].ToString();
        int b = int.Parse(SavedAchievementFromDB); // Trying to Save The num of Goals from DataBase to int
        int GoalsAfterSum = b + int.Parse(((SoccerTable.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("AchNums") as DropDownList).Text.Trim())); // Trying to sum
        string query = "UPDATE SoccerAchievements SET Achievement='" + GoalsAfterSum + "' WHERE PlayerCode = @id"; // Trying to Update
        OleDbCommand sqlCmd = new OleDbCommand(query, sqlCon);
        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Goals", (SoccerTable.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("AchNums") as DropDownList).Text.Trim());
        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", Convert.ToInt32(SoccerTable.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString()));
        sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the error that you are getting?

Comment: This is causing the error most likely even though you've not told us the error: `SoccerTable.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("AchNums") as DropDownList).Text()` because I am pretty sure that does not return what you think it should be returning.

Comment: oh sry i will update my post: look now and see the error

Comment: Try `SoccerTable.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("AchNums") as DropDownList). SelectedItem.Value` instead

Comment: Bro i am not getting error right now...

Comment: I want to save my database value to a new paramter and then sum it and update to my database...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to get the value from the database before updating, you can just update the value in the SQL statement `UPDATE SoccerAchievements SET Achievement = Achievement + @Goals`.

```
    using (OleDbConnection sqlCon = new OleDbConnection(connectionStr))
    {
        sqlCon.Open();

        // get the goals from the web control
        string goalsText = (SoccerTable.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("AchNums") as DropDownList).Text.Trim();

        // try to parse goals to int
        if (!int.TryParse(goalsText, out int goals))
        {
            // handle error
        }

        // try to parse user id to int
        if (!int.TryParse(SoccerTable.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString(), out int id))
        {
            // handle error
        }

        // increment the value in sql statement
        string query = "UPDATE SoccerAchievements SET Achievement = Achievement + @Goals WHERE UserID = @id";

        OleDbCommand sqlCmd = new OleDbCommand(query, sqlCon);
        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Goals", goals);
        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id));

        sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        lblSuccessMessage.Text = "עריכת הנתונים התבצעה בהצלחה";
        lblErrorMessage.Text = "";
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, Can you please edit you message and write it good because i copy paste and its doing erros

Comment: Never Mind bro i got it

Comment: Thank you very Much you helped me so much i really like it

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.